# Workaround or fix for VS messing up Knockout binding attribute?

Tags: visual-studio, knockout.js

Whenever one of my `data-bind` attribute spans two lines. Visual Studio strips out all of the colons.

Has anyone else experienced this? Has anyone found a workaround or fix?
I am not sure if it is VS or some extension that I installed. Maybe Web Extensions or something.

I am currently using VS2015 I had the same issue with VS2013

You can see it most immediately when you try to copy and paste it. But then sometimes it'll just happen. I'll see a page that worked perfectly before just up and break and the reason is because VS formatted my knockoutjs binding attribute.

My most common scenario is select tags which tend to get real long.

Here is an example.

Before:

```
<select class="input-block-level" data-bind="value: DayId, options: $parent.availableDays,
    optionsText: 'DisplayName' , optionsValue: 'Id' , optionsCaption: '--' "></select>
```

After:

```
<select class="input-block-level" data-bind=" value DayId, options $parent.availableDays,
    optionsText 'DisplayName' , optionsValue 'Id' , optionsCaption '--' "></select>
```

Comment: Where in the data-bind is your line break?  In Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, I break lines after the comma on multiple-parameter data-binds without any problems.

Comment: What does 'B"H' mean?

Comment: Please help us reproduce your issue. Tell us what version of visual studio you're using, how up to date it is / whether you've tried updating it completely, what plugins you have installed and whether turning them on/off made a difference. If possible, use e.g. Licecap to capture an animated gif of the behavior, and/or add a precise repro with full code and steps for your scenario.

Comment: I am currently using VS2015 I had the same issue with VS2013

Comment: @Tomalak [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321360/107625).